# See someone= Meet/Hangout with someone?

Tags: word-meaning

"We used to work out together everyday and hangout on weekends. He lives in the US now. So I **don't get to see him anymore**."

Does 'see someone' mean meeting or hanging out with someone?

Comment: It can mean that. It can also mean literally seeing them (with your eyes)

Comment: I was talking about a friend. Have I used 'see' correctly here?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, it simply means to *see* them in person - to be in their company.

To be *seeing someone* can also imply a romantic relationship.

Comment: I was talking about a friend. Have I used 'see' correctly here?

Comment: Yes, you have. I was just warning you about a possible other meaning of 'see'.